# HIVE Pivot and Sum/count

Tags: sql, pyspark, hive, pivot, pivot-table

I have a fake data table that I am trying to figure out how to pivot and sum/count based on the values.

Example input:
[image]

Example output:
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter by fruit flag, aggregate for each and union all results:

```
select 'apple_flg'                  as fruit_name
       count(distinct student_name) as cnt_student, --if student_name is unique, no distinct needed
       sum(buy_cnt)                 as sum_buy_cnt,
       sum(buy_payment)             as sum_buy_payment 
 from tablename
where apple_flg=1 

union all

select 'banana_flg'                 as fruit_name
       count(distinct student_name) as cnt_student,
       sum(buy_cnt)                 as sum_buy_cnt,
       sum(buy_payment)             as sum_buy_payment 
 from tablename
where banana_flg=1

union all

select 'strawberry_flg'             as fruit_name
       count(distinct student_name) as cnt_student,
       sum(buy_cnt)                 as sum_buy_cnt,
       sum(buy_payment)             as sum_buy_payment 
 from tablename
where strawberry_flg=1 

union all

select 'watermelon_flg'             as fruit_name
       count(distinct student_name) as cnt_student, 
       sum(buy_cnt)                 as sum_buy_cnt,
       sum(buy_payment)             as sum_buy_payment
 from tablename 
where watermelon_flg=1 

union all

select 'lemon_flg'                  as fruit_name
       count(distinct student_name) as cnt_student, 
       sum(buy_cnt)                 as sum_buy_cnt,
       sum(buy_payment)             as sum_buy_payment 
 from tablename
where lemon_flg=1
```

One more possible approach:

```
select case when apple_flg=1       then 'apple_flg'
            when banana_flg=1      then 'banana_flg'
            when strawberry_flg=1  then 'strawberry_flg'
            when watermelon_flg=1  then 'watermelon_flg'
            when lemon_flg=1       then 'lemon_flg'
        end                         as fruit,
       count(distinct student_name) as cnt_student,
       sum(buy_cnt)                 as sum_buy_cnt,
       sum(buy_payment)             as sum_buy_payment 
 from tablename
group by apple_flg, banana_flg, strawberry_flg, watermelon_flg, lemon_flg
```

If some fruits are never purchased and you need those rows with 0 counts, you may need more complex solution:

```
with fruits as (
select stack(5, 'apple_flg',
                'banana_flg',
                'strawberry_flg',
                'watermelon_flg',
                'lemon_flg'
           ) as fruit
),

agg as (
select case when apple_flg=1       then 'apple_flg'
            when banana_flg=1      then 'banana_flg'
            when strawberry_flg=1  then 'strawberry_flg'
            when watermelon_flg=1  then 'watermelon_flg'
            when lemon_flg=1       then 'lemon_flg'
        end                         as fruit,
       count(distinct student_name) as cnt_student,
       sum(buy_cnt)                 as sum_buy_cnt,
       sum(buy_payment)             as sum_buy_payment 
 from tablename
group by apple_flg, banana_flg, strawberry_flg, watermelon_flg, lemon_flg
)

select f.fruit,
       nvl(s.cnt_student, 0)     as cnt_student,
       nvl(s.sum_buy_cnt, 0)     as sum_buy_cnt,
       nvl(s.sum_buy_payment, 0) as sum_buy_payment
  from fruits f
       left join agg s on f.fruit=s.fruit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was worked !!!Thank you well mush!